# Powershell script to upload to skydrive for offsite backup?

Tags: backup, powershell

anyone one got one?  or can point me to the resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out:

http://igorshare.wordpress.com/2008/02/22/skydrive-powershell-provider-far-beyond-reach/

Comment: thanks for this - not seen it - shame as this skydrive is now 25gb useful.